# Array comparison (non-empty set intersection) in Postgres query (can't coerce)

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a Plone web application which uses `psycopg2` (currently 2.5.5) to access a Postgres database (9.1 or 9.3, depending on the machine).

I have application-side groups, given by group ids (e.g. `group_a`, `group_b`) and a view which yields an array of group ids in one of the fields (e.g. `group_ids` = `{group_b,group_c}`. The user can be member of several groups. I want to select all rows where the intersection of the user's groups (Python: `('group_a', 'group_b')`) and the view's groups (SQL: `{group_b,group_c}`) is not empty.

My first attempt was to throw the user's groups to psycopg2:

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM view_name WHERE group_ids = ANY(%(group_ids)s);',
         None,
         {'group_ids': ('group_a', 'group_b')})
```

but this didn't work (sorry, German error message; I didn't get an English text even in a `psql` shell with `LANG=C`):

```
FEHLER: konnte Arraytyp für Datentyp character varying[] nicht finden
```

... which means, Postgres is confused by the `character varying[]` values in the `group_ids` array.  So what can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated: to get English error message you need to set `LC_MESSAGES=English` (OS environment variable) not `LANG`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry, didn't work:  perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_MESSAGES = "English",
        LANG = "de_DE.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

Comment: No idea about Perl, but setting `LC_MESSAGES=English` works for me in `psql` (or Java)

Comment: Seems `psql` uses Perl somewhere under the hood. I tried to set all values both to `C` or `English`; didn't work. But perhaps someone knows where to look up the messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the overlap [`&&` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html) instead of `= ANY()`:

```
SELECT * FROM view_name WHERE group_ids && '{group_a,group_b}';
```

If I'm reading the [`psycopg2` documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation) correctly, I think you should also be passing a `list` instead of a `tuple`:

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM view_name WHERE group_ids && %(group_ids)s::character varying[];',
         None,
         {'group_ids': ['group_a', 'group_b']})
```

Comment: Yes, right; during my first attempts it made no visible difference for the error, but a list is needed. Neither tuples nor sets are accepted ...